# What are the "line" numbers in Wireshark (and other hex editors/viewers)?

Tags: wireshark, hex-editor, hexdump

This is probably a really simple question that has an answer elsewhere, but I couldn't think of the right words to make an effective search, so here I am. Obviously, if this is a duplicate question, feel free to vote to close.

Can someone please explain what the ["line" numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FY1A.jpg) (`0000`, `0010`, `0020`, etc - I couldn't think of a better word to describe them) mean in wireshark and other hex editors?

There are 16 bytes in a line so I'm guessing it's not the byte offset - what are they?

Again, apologies if this is a silly question that has an answer elsewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is byte offset, but in hexadecimal system.

If a line starts with offset `0010`, then:

- 1st value is at offset `0010`
- 10th value is at offset `0019`
- 11th value is at offset `001A`
- 16th value is at offset `001F`
- 1st value on next line is at offset `0020`, which is the number directly following `001F` in hexadecimal

Comment: Ok that makes sense I think. So on the first line the offset of each byte would be (respectively, from first to last byte): `0000`, `0001`, `0002`, `0003`, `0004`, `0005`, `0006`, `0007`, `0008`, `0009`, `000A`, `000B`, `000C`, `000D`, `000E`, `000F`?

Comment: @ResetACK That's correct.